# Remove Social and Comments Footer From SPO Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

**Other than scripting** the removal of the Comments and Social footer from a Site Page, is there a way to remove the objects using the GUI?

For reference, here is the SP PNP command I'm using to remove the objects.

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled $True -CommentsOnSitePagesDisabled $True
```

Comment: You can turn off commenting on a page-by-page basis, but I don't think there is a UI yet for turning these on/off for the whole site.

Comment: @willman i'm currently testing the idea of making a page template from a page that has been cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done through the GUI as well - either in each page level or global level from admin center.

Disable the comments footer from admin center (global setting) :

1. Navigate to Admin Centers by going to App Launcher > Admin
2. Under Admin Centers, choose SharePoint
3. Once in SharePoint Admin Center, click on Settings
4. Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the Settings screen to Comments on Site Pages section. By default, comments are enabled on all pages. If you wish to disable, just choose appropriate radio button and click OK

Example:
Go to this URL:

```
https://globalsharepoint2019-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx
```

And please do below-highlighted settings:

[image: Comments on Site Pages admin center]

[image: Commests settings in admin center2]

NOTES:

- And I think for the social collaboration setting, you can check the "Enterprise Social Collaboration" setting from the same global setting page.
- This global setting option usually takes 10-20 minutes to take effect
  on all sites/pages in your tenant
- Once disabled globally, comments cannot be enabled back by Site
  Owners or Site Members
- Just like with previous option, disabling comments globally does not
  remove the comments history. Once globally enabled, the whole
  Comments thread will be back!

Disable the comments footer from site page level :

1. Edit the page by clicking the Editbutton
2. At the bottom of the page in the Comments section, toggle the switch from On position…

Please refer the below article for the details:

[2 ways to disable modern page comments](https://sharepointmaven.com/2-ways-to-disable-modern-page-comments/)

Comment: The settings page is located here:  https:// YourSITE- admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx

Comment: From the Admin center, you have to select Yammer or SP Newsfeed, there's no option to totally disable Social Collab. ... I'm going to continue trying to make a custom Site Page with none of the added junk on it.  thx!

Comment: Please see my updated screen shot of disabling comments in global setting.

Comment: how can it be done in SharePoint on-premises?